# nl2br returns <br />\r\n, how to make all built in PHP functions return \n instead?

Tags: php, line-breaks, nl2br

Don't get me wrong, I'm not bothered about the pre PHP 5.3.0 xhtml `<br />` tags, and I can easily replace the \r\n with \n, of course.

Thing is I want some sort of global setting on this pre PHP 5.3.0 server to make all similar built in PHP functions to understand that a correct line break between the HTML lines I want to output is a \n, not a \r\n.

Do I want what I shouldn't want? Is it an impossible dream? Or did I just forget the ungooglable constant. There are no end to the questions.

Either way, just an answer to the one in subject would make me happy :) Is it possible, or do I have to str_replace the entire article string once I've built it. Thanks. BTW, Elvis lives. Or at least, 'lives' is an anagram of 'elvis' which is good enough for me since I wasn't really a fan.

In short, I want to save a byte per newline in the HTTPRESULT.

Comment: Is all of this unnecessary noise a consequence of you not being able to get your original question through the low-quality filter?

Comment: php's probably returning PHP_EOL, which is platform-dependent. if you're on windows, you'll get `\r\n`.

Comment: Robert Harvey: No, the unnecessary noise is due to me being in a good mood! After searching on google and SO. Trick question: are comments that don't ask more detail or make suggestions considered unnecessary noise? ;)

Marc B: PHP_EOL is for reading. PHP, which produces the \r\n output, is running on a standard shared hosting Apache server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nl2br()` uses whatever line endings were present in its input. If you don't want to see `\r\n` in the output, convert it to `\n` before you pass it in.

This isn't explicitly stated in [the documentation for this function](https://www.php.net/nl2br), but it's implied heavily by the description, which reads (emphasis mine):

> Returns string with `'<br />'` or `'<br>'` **inserted before** all newlines (`\r\n`, `\n\r`, `\n` and `\r`).

And it's borne out by testing.